# Did the magic erase Vicky's memory?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-fairly-oddparents

In *The Fairly OddParents* S04E08 (*Vicky Loses Her Icky*), Timmy wished for Vicky to be nice.

Vicky was breaking the door of Timmy's room prior to the magic being done.

After she became nice, she told Timmy:

> You were attacked by a door!

So she doesn't remember her recent acts, and probably she doesn't remember all of her mean acts towards Timmy in this scene (because she didn't apologize to Timmy for her bad treatments). Of course, she remembers Timmy himself.

Timmy didn't tell Cosmo and Wanda to erase her memory; he just told them to make Vicky a nice person.

Is erasing the memory of mean acts by someone necessary for making them nice?

Furthermore, was the memory of mean acts stored in that evil beetle, and when it came back to Vicky's body, she remembered her mean acts against Timmy and became bad again?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is some sort of "ripple effect", intended to prevent Vicky (or anyone else who might be affected by such a spell) from recognising that anything has changed. If she realises her personality has suddenly changed so drastically, she may investigate the cause, and in doing so, she may discover the existence of magic and fairies. Which would be very, *very* bad. Vicky getting bitten by the bug at the end of the episode undoes the spell, for all intents and purposes, and so her memory is restored.

There's no canon confirmation of this, but it fits with other examples we see throughout the series:

- In "The Switch Glitch", Timmy has Vicky magically de-aged to five so he can get his revenge on her. She doesn't remember being 16, or who Timmy is at all, let alone what she did to him - Timmy has to introduce himself to her.

> Hello, Vicky. You're five. And I'm your ten-year-old babysitter Timmy.

Timmy even admits at the end of the episode that, once he wishes Vicky back to normal, she won't remember a thing.

- In "Tiny Timmy!", Timmy shrinks down into Vicky's body. While inside her emotional control center, he surreptitiously dials her "Kindness" level all the way up. Vicky notices the change ("I'm becoming... KIND!"), but once it kicks in she doesn't seem to remember who she was previously, and starts cleaning the house without acknowledging that she was the one who messed it up in the first place. When her Kindness is dialled back down to normal (i.e. zero), she instantly forgets what she was doing the moment before:

> What the...? Cute animals? And they're *cleaning?!* ***GET OUT!***

- On the other hand, in "Snow Bound", when Vicky's anger cools off *naturally*, it has no effect on her memory. Sure enough, the *very first thing she does* is burst into tears and apologise to Timmy for how she treated him. When her anger returns at the end of the episode, she still remembers everything that happened.
- Similarly, in "Emotion Commotion!", when Timmy erases (and later regains) his emotions, he doesn't seem to forget anything. This makes sense - Timmy already knows that his fairies are responsible, so there's no need to mess with his memory.